# How to dim out a GraphicControl

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a TCard ( TGraphicControl component) and it has a property
background (TPicture)

I would like to be able to dim out  or darken the background. Thus if i can play the card in the game then its normal. If i can not play the card in the game then its darken out. I have tried putting `Tcard.enabled :=false` Like you would a button, but it does not dim it out or darken the image / background.

Also I could not find a alphablend property for TPicture as i thought this might help.

With what property or component would i need to get this effect?

Comment: You could paint to an offscreen bitmap, then convert to greyscale, and then blit to the canvas.

Comment: Well on the form , if the TCard can be "played" then its normal color if it can not be "played" then i wanted it darken.. I cant find any way to adjust the alphablend for a TPicture. As background is a TPicture in the custom component TCard(tgraphicControl).. This is my final goal i guess. maybe i should reword the question? but this choosing effect you talk about.. would this allow me to do as i am asking?

Comment: How will alpha blending help you? Or do you want to make your card translucent to indicate disabled? Can you explain why you talk about `TGraphicControl` and `TPicture`? Which is it?

Comment: @GlenMorse Remember that all the information available to us is what appears in the question. Alpha blending can do many things, but it's typically used with transparency effects. That's what the alpha channel is about. What effect to you actually want to achieve?

Comment: See this image,  it has some cards dark while others are nomal..i am trying for this effect  http://garethfouche.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Kard-Combat-Gameplay-280x420.jpg

Comment: thanks TLama i will give this approach a try.. though it does seem more confusing loading into a buffer then transferring it over..but if 1. it does the effect and 2. its faster then ill try it :D also please dont delete link

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Handling Enabled

Following your example, the enabled state of `TButton` is drawn by Windows. For your own control, a visual reflection of a disabled state should be drawn by yourself. Within the overriden `Paint` routine this will simply mean:

```
if Enabled then
  // draw enabled
else
  // draw disabled;
```

The VCL takes care of handling a change of the `Enabled` property, since it calls Invalidate on the  `CM_ENABLEDCHANGED` message.

#### Drawing dimmed

The most simple solution is to draw all that has to be drawn [alphablended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183351(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
procedure TCard.Paint;
var
  Tmp: TBitmap;
  BlendFunc: TBlendFunction;
begin
  if Enabled then
    InternalPaint(Canvas)
  else
  begin
    Tmp := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      Tmp.SetSize(Width, Height);
      InternalPaint(Tmp.Canvas);
      BlendFunc.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
      BlendFunc.BlendFlags := 0;
      BlendFunc.SourceConstantAlpha := 80;
      BlendFunc.AlphaFormat := 0;
      WinApi.Windows.AlphaBlend(Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Width, Height,
        Tmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Width, Height, BlendFunc);
    finally
      Tmp.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Wherein the `InternalPaint` routine does everything you are doing now, for example:

```
procedure TCard.InternalPaint(ACanvas: TCanvas);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  R := ClientRect;
  ACanvas.Brush.Color := clGray;
  ACanvas.Rectangle(R);
  InflateRect(R, -7, -7);
  if (FPicture.Graphic <> nil) and (not FPicture.Graphic.Empty) then
    ACanvas.StretchDraw(R, FPicture.Graphic);
end;
```

All this with the following result:

[image: screenshot]

The `SourceConstantAlpha` factor (max `255`) signifies by how much the temporarily bitmap is blended with the destination surface. The default color of the Canvas is the color of the Parent (assuming you do not interfere with erasing background or something), which is `clBtnFace` in the above image. If that destination is all white, then the bitmap is faded to white.  If you would like a blending color or a darkened effect, then add these two lines before AlphaBlend:

```
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack; //or clMaroon
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
```

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Great answer and cant wait to try it.  btw whats the image?

Comment: what include do i need to use WinAPI?

Comment: `WinApi.Windows` since you have XE2. But you don't have to qualify; it's a remnant of me making use of code-completion: `Windows.AlphaBlend` or just `AlphaBlend` probably will work just fine.